# How to get the email address in between 2 different characters in Excel or Google Sheets using formula only?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The cell A2 has the following sample email address:

```
Jose Rizal <jose@email.com>
```

I want to get the email address only in cell B2:

```
=right(A2,len(A2) - search("<",A2,1))
```

but the result was: **jose@email.com>** (with the > on the last character).

The table looks like this and the expected result is on B2:

```
  |            A                |          B         |
 1| complete email address      | email address only |
 2| Jose Rizal <jose@email.com> | jose@email.com     |
```

What to improve on my formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste in B2:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "<(.*)>")
```

[image: 0]

and arrayformula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "<(.*)>")))
```

Comment: (sigh).... it's times like these where I wish Excel had a regex formula.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, or Google sheets(But [player0's REGEXEXTRACT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614838/4851590) is better to use in Google Sheets):

```
=MID(REPLACE(A2,FIND(">",A2),LEN(A2),""),FIND("<",A2)+1,LEN(A2))
```

And drag the formula down.

[image]

Comment: Soo... is there a REGEX-like formula coming out or do we have to wait for that one?

Comment: Dang it, I had my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

Add another Left trim in there:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2) - SEARCH("<",A2,1)),LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2) - SEARCH("<",A2,1)))-1)
```

Comment: thank you [K753](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11104095/k753)

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt using **FILTERXML** if you are using one of the following versions of Excel:

[image: FILTERXML]

```
=FILTERXML("<b><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),"<","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a[2]")
```

Suppose your data stars from Cell `A2`, drag the formula down to apply across.

> For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).